# truncateFileAtOffset runtime error

Tags: objective-c

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

int main(int argc, const char * argv[])
{

@autoreleasepool {

    NSFileHandle *inFile, *outFile;
    NSData *buffer;

    //Open the test file for reading

    inFile = [NSFileHandle fileHandleForReadingAtPath:@"testfile"];

    if (inFile == nil) {
        NSLog(@"Open of testfile reading failed");
        return 1;
    }

    //Create output file if necessary

    [[NSFileManager defaultManager] createFileAtPath:@"testout" contents:nil attributes:nil];

    //Now open the output file for writing

    outFile = [NSFileHandle fileHandleForReadingAtPath:@"testout"];

    if (outFile == nil) {
        NSLog(@"Open of testout for writing ailed");
        return 2;
    }

    //Truncate the output file as it may contain data

    [outFile truncateFileAtOffset: 0];

    //Read the data from infile and write it out to out file

    buffer = [inFile readDataToEndOfFile];
    [outFile writeData:buffer];

    //Close both the files

    [inFile closeFile];
    [outFile closeFile];

    //Verify the files contents

    NSLog(@"%@", [NSString stringWithContentsOfFile:@"testout" encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding error:NULL]);

}
return 0;
}
```

The program is compiling correctly but I am getting an error at the line `[outFile truncateFileAtOffset: 0];`

The error Which I am getting is:
    2014-04-01 20:38:39.220 16.7[7752:303] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSFileHandleOperationException', reason: '** -[NSConcreteFileHandle truncateFileAtOffset:]: Invalid argument'
** First throw call stack:
(
    0   CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff8884525c __exceptionPreprocess + 172
    1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x00007fff8d752e75 objc_exception_throw + 43
    2   CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff8884510c +[NSException raise:format:] + 204
    3   16.7                                0x0000000100000c7e main + 414
    4   libdyld.dylib                       0x00007fff91add5fd start + 1
    5   ???                                 0x0000000000000001 0x0 + 1
)
libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException
(lldb)

If I am removing this line, I am getting another error in [outFile writeData:buffer];

I have just typed in as-is from the book.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This line:

```
outFile = [NSFileHandle fileHandleForReadingAtPath:@"testout"];
```

I suspect you are wanting:

```
outFile = [NSFileHandle fileHandleForWritingAtPath:@"testout"];
```

Writing a file allows you to truncate it.

Comment: I shouldn't depend on autocomplete too much